# TryParseExact failing with DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5, datetime-format, tryparse

I am coding an `MVC 5` internet application and I have a `Bootstrap DateTimePicker` control (https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) to select a `DateTime`. Before I add the `DateTime` value to a model object, I use the `TryParseExact` function to check that the `DateTime` is valid.

I am getting an error with the `TryParseExact` code.

Here is an example:

The selected `DateTime` is `30 December 2015` with the `DateTimePicker`. This is displayed as:

```
12/30/2015 3:09:32 PM
```

My `TryParseExact` code is as follows:

```
DateTime mapLocationStartDate;
string format = "MM-dd-yyyy h:mm:ss tt";
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(iMapLocationDate.displayMapLocationStartDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out mapLocationStartDate))
{

}
```

`12/30/2015 3:09:32 PM` fails the `TryParseExact` code.

Can I please have some help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your value uses `/` as date separator but your format expected `-`. Why do you expect that to parse correctly?

Comment: The date displayed in the control is most likely formatted differently than the date sent over the wire and parsed by your code. Have a look at the date on the server side to determine which format to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your iMapLocationDate.displayMapLocationStartDate value is "12/30/2015 3:09:32 PM" and you expect it to be always in this format, then use a format that exactly match it.

Please try this format instead:

```
string format = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";
```